# 301 redirecting blog links that don't start with `/blog` to the new blog location

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I had a WordPress site that I moved folders - `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/blog`.

The problem now is that many sites still link to my old blog links to `/blog-post` so when users click on them they get a 404. There's roughly about 100 links like these, however they don't all follow the same URL structure.

For example:

- `/blog-post`
- `/postname`
- `/2016/01/01/post`

Is there any way for me to make those links take them to their NEW locations - which would be just prepending `/blog/`?

Comment: Do you have any other content in the root directory other than the blog?   Is there anything else that the rule would have to be careful not to redirect?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller unfortunately yes - index.php, about.php for example and css folders.

Comment: Does `index.php` use rewrite rules to handle many URLs (like WordPress does) or is it just the single URL?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller just the single URL

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your root `.htaccess` file (using mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)
RewriteRule !^blog /blog/%1 [R=301,L]
```

For all URLs that don't start `/blog` and don't exist as physical files (in the document root, or anywhere for that matter) then 301 redirect to `/blog/<whatever>`.

Make sure you clear the browser cache if you've previously tested 301s that have failed.